# Google Glass - replace in app context menu trigger 'ok glass' voice trigger with the actual top level menu selections as voice triggers instead

Tags: android, google-glass

I've seen a couple of examples where on phone the voice recognizer is running as a background service - constantly listening and processing speech. I can't tell if implementing such services is restricted in the current GDK.

I'm prototyping a warehousing app and we'd like to use voice to pick from several top-level menu options without uttering 'ok glass' to invoke the initial menu context.

Anyone have a preferred example of this or know if/why it can't be done with the current GDK?

Thanks!

Comment: So far as of the end of this business day, I can say that continuous speech seems work just like a regular phone implementation where recognizing is running in a service and results are broadcast back to a receiver activity.

Comment: Actually after implementing this as speech recognition running in a service, I'm not sure exactly why I thought SR needed to run in a service in the first place. Just seems to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize the naivety of the original question. I just ended up using the sdk speech recognizer and implemented the callbacks. To make the recognizer work continuously, I restart it on error or after it has delivered a set of results. I additionally added some state-indication UI to my activity that gives visual feedback to the user as the recognizer moves from listening to non-listening and back to listening states.